# "Expected ]" error while passing an object as parameter to js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to pass an object as parameter to the javascript function as:

```
    .html('<span class="link" onclick="javascript:ShowEventDetails(' + event + ',' 
    + event.Id + ',' + event.Name + ',' + view + ')">' + event.title 
+ '</span>')
```

In the above js, the `event` and `view` are objects from the jquery calendar `Full Calendar`, which i am passing to call a js function.

It throws an error, `Expected ']'`. What may be problem or how to pass an object as above?

It shows `"javascript:ShowEditEventDetails([object Object],1,'Name',[object Object])"` while looking in firebug.

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET, you could also be getting the error from the ShowEventDetails function.  I don't know if this is just a debugging thing in Visual Studio 2008 SP1, but I spent about an hour tracking down a very similar problem.

Comment: it just throws the error on page load itself. i.e. while constructing the html itself. Also its not hitting to that function while using debugger.

Comment: Try it in Firefox with the Firebug debugger and see if you get any insight. Look at the Console for interesting error messages.

Comment: it shows the result as i given in the question with the error "missing ] after element list"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass an object in that way, because when you concatenate the HTML string of your `span` element, all the operands of the `+` operator are converted `toString`, including the  `event` object, that's why you get `"[object Object]"`:

```
'' + {} == "[object Object]"; // an empty object
```

I would recommend you to bind the click event programmatically:

```
// ...
var $span = $('<span class="link">' + event.title + '</span>');
$span.click(function () {
  ShowEventDetails(event, event.Id, event.Name, view);
});

$('#otherElement').append($span);
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `ShowEventDetails` isn't being passed `event`, it's being passed `String(event)`, which is `[object Object]`, which yields a syntax error. Assuming `event` and `view` are global variables, use this instead:

```
.html('<span class="link" onclick="javascript:ShowEventDetails(event,' 
      + event.Id + ',' + event.Name + ',view)">' + event.title 
      + '</span>')
```

You shouldn't be using .html for such a thing though. This solution is better and doesn't require global variables:

```
.addClass("link")
.click(function () {
  ShowEventDetails(event, event.Id, event.Name, view)
})
.text(event.title);
```

Answer (score 0):

**What's Going Wrong**

`event` and `view` are both objects.  When you concatenate an object to a string (as you're doing with `'...ShowEventDetails(' + event + ','...`), JavaScript casts the object to a string, resulting in the nearly useless `[object Object]` text you see in FireBug.  When the JavaScript interpreter later tries to parse `[object Object]` as code, it blows up because it is invalid syntax.

**How to Fix It**

The easiest thing to do is set your event handler programmatically:

```
var mySpan = $('<span class="link" />');
mySpan.text(event.title);
mySpan.click(function (ev) {
  ShowEventDetails(event, event.Id, event.Name, view);
});

parentElement.append(mySpan);
```